# CRUD in Html table

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, crud

I have put an HTML table in Asp.net MVC view which is dynamically filled from DATABASE. No i want to delete , edit, update records in database using HTML table, i want to implement CRUD in HTML table.

Code:

```
namespace Testing_linq.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
            var DataContext = new RegistrationDataContext();
            var Registration = DataContext.SelectRegistration_sp();

            return View(Registration);
        }
```

View:

```
<table>
@foreach(SelectRegistration_spResult reg in (IEnumerable<Object>)ViewData.Model)
{
    <tr>
     <td><button type="button">Delete</button> </td>
     <td>@reg.userEmail </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: So, what's your specific question?  I don't see delete, edit, insert buttons in your HTML.  I don't see any javascript to make ajax calls to your server.  What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: my question is that HOW TO DELTE FROM TABLE which actually should delete from database too, same goes for editing

Comment: Conceptually, you make an ajax call from the browser javascript that calls a script on your server and that script on your server pulls instructions from the ajax call and modifies the database accordingly.  There are lots of examples of doing this on the web, but your question as it stands now is far too broad for a simple answer here.

Comment: ok sir atleast provide me link to those examples , i can't find any like that

Comment: Search for "crud ajax asp sample" in your favorite search engine.